# Measure Java execution time (Real, User, System) like linux command

Tags: java, time, kernel, benchmarking, execution-time

I have a massive parallel Java-Application and want to measure its execution time the very same way that linux' `time` command does it (Real, User, System).

I'm especially interested in the time the application spends in kernel-tasks, i.e. shows suboptimal behavior (the higher the ratio of system/(system+user), the worse the performance).

In bash, there is `time`, for C++ there are boost/std `chrono` .. Is there anything for Java?

I found [OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuTime()), but it seems this is a dead end for measuring time in kernel-tasks.

Comment: `time java foo.jar` maybe?  Or if you can use POSIX / Linux system calls from Java code or via JNI, you can always call `getrusage` to get the same info that `bash`'s `time` built-in prints, and more.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html  (same for `/usr/bin/time` which prints more detail.)

Comment: sure, I could just use `time`  from the outside; but I'd like to build a unit-test from java around the `system/(user+system)`-metric